# Amazon Web Services (AWS) SDK 1.6 - PHP - Returns absolutely nothing

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, sdk

Just trying to get past the first hurdle with AWS.
We've had to use the older verion of the SDK - 1.6.2 because our servers all run PHP 5.2 which doesn't have namespace support.

I have created my config file and popped my deets in, I am including the sdk.class.php etc like so:

```
    $file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/lib/aws-sdk-1.6.2/sdk.class.php";
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        require_once ($file);
        $ec2 = new AmazonEC2();
        $response = $ec2->describe_availability_zones();
        print_r($response);
    } else {
        die('No file');
    }
```

In here I am also dumping the response but for every call I do to whichever service I just get a completely blank response. Not a zero, no blank array, not even the word null.

Without any output to view I am completely stumped. Any ideas on how to even get it to tell me where the problem could be would be amazing.

Thanks!

Comment: Nothing in the logs like aws throwing an exception?

Comment: Ah - yes - well that is weird I do:

Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error

Which could be my .htaccess but that would be strange

Comment: Scrap that - that was from hours ago. So looks like that is nothing to do with it :(

Comment: 100% sure it's not going in the else ? What is var_dump of ($ec2)

Comment: Hmm - well it's definitely not going to else but it's not getting past $response = $ec2->describe_availability_zones();

Here's the dump:

Comment: http://hlpn.devg.es/dump.txt

Comment: try wrapping after require_once to print_r in a try { } statement, if it passes then then you know aws is throwing an exception. use $e->getMessage() to print out the exception

Comment: Also make sure your environment meets these requirements: The cURL PHP extension (compiled with the OpenSSL libraries for HTTPS support).
The ability to read from and write to the file system via file_get_contents() and file_put_contents().

Comment: That comes out blank too but it doesn't do anything past the try statement - which sounds like it is deliberately dying. I'm just following it through the class. Will report back.. thanks!

Comment: It looks like it is the SSL certificate. Originally it threw that error up until I installed OpenSSL bit I had put an echo and exit in requestcore.class.php file to try and see if it had accepted my manual certificate. When I take that out the try method shows that it needs the certificate still. So I need to either try with the manual certificate method or I need to do something with OpenSSL.